# Sd card encryption forgotten password

Tags: external-sd

I've forgotten my password so I can't deactivate my encrypted SD card in my Samsung S9. Is there anything I can do please?

Comment: Is it used as portable storage or adoptable-storage?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't clearly mentioned what type of encryption it is...
Anyway, I'll tell you a general solution. I'm not 100% sure if this will work. Also, this may not work if the SD card was used as adoptable storage at the time of mounting it on the S9. I'm also not sure if this will work if you have used Samsung Knox to encrypt it..

---

### **WARNING** : This method will completely erase any data you have on the SD card. I'm not responsible for any data loss. This will only give you your SD card back in a usable form.

• Insert the SD card into a Windows machine (preferably Windows 10) using an SD card reader.

• The system will automatically allot a drive letter to the SD card. It's in this step where the problem lies. Depending on the type of encryption, the system may or may not detect the SD card.

• If it detects the card, note the drive letter. Else if it doesn't detect the card, just simply follow these steps.

• Right click on the Start icon

• Select Disk Management

• If the card was detected earlier, it will display the SD card as *online* along with the drive letter. It will also list one (or more) partitions. There may be some listed as **Healthy Primary Partitions** and some other **Unallocated spaces**. If it hadn't detected the card, there is a possibility that it may display the the drive as just *unallocated space*.

• Even if there are no unallocated spaces, just right click on the Healthy partitions and click delete volume. Repeat this for all partitions in the SD card. If there are only unallocated spaces, right click on that space and then select **New Simple Volume**

• Then, all the partitions will combine together to form a single **Unallocated Space**

• Now, right click on the unallocated space and click on the **New Simple Volume** option.

• A new Simple Volume Wizard will pop up. Follow the prompts the wizard gives to create a new Simple Volume.

• Exit the Disk Management utility and eject the SD card .

That's it. If you're lucky, you'll be able to get the SD card back to life. Please don't blame me if this doesn't work. I'm just guessing it will. Sorry if this doesn't work...